# "На три месяца вперед" или "за три месяца вперед"

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно написать?

Готовы вносить арендную плату на три месяца вперед на постоянной основе.

Или

Готовы вносить арендную плату за три месяца вперед на постоянной основе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно: арендную плату **за три месяца**.

ПЛАТА,  ж. 2. Денежное возмещение за пользование чем-л., за какие-л. услуги. Квартирная п. Проездная п. **П. за радио. П. за проживание в гостинице. Задержать плату за газ. Повысить плату за проезд в общественном транспорте.**

Answer (score 2):

Здесь нужно разглядеть выражения **платить** (здесь: вносить арендную плату) **вперёд** (т. е. до начала получения услуги, до получения товара и т. п.) и **платить за три месяца** (аренды). Недоразумение с предлогом возникает из-за схожести с выражением "***на*** три месяца раньше (чего-то)" - здесь нет такого буквального смысла, *платят* же всегда **за** что-то (услугу в количестве, измеряемом тремя месяцами аренды, товар в количестве таком-то).

Готовы **вносить** арендную **плату вперёд**. Плату за какой период? **За** три месяца. Плата вносится **за** каждые три месяца (такова минимально оплачиваемая длительность услуги), и эта плата **вносится вперёд** (= до начала оказания услуги в указанном размере).

> Готовы на постоянной основе вносить арендную плату вперёд **за** три
>   месяца.

**P.S.** Пример из Полного собрания законов Российской Империи, 1830:

> ... дозволяется **платить впередъ** и **за все время** пивоваренія.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, выражение "плата за три месяца вперед" употребимо только в случае одноразового действия (например, при заключении договора арендатор оплатил три месяца проживания вперед). Как это делать "на постоянной основе" интуитивно понятно, но "постоянная основа" звучит слишком расплывчато. Я бы сказал так: 
**Готовы вносить арендную плату за каждые три месяца авансом**. Здесь есть и порядок оплаты (каждые три месяца), и сроки (авансом).

Но если вам так любо выражение "за три месяца вперед", то возможен такой вариант: **Готовы каждые три месяца вносить арендную плату за следующие три месяца вперед.**

Comment: Из словаря: ВПЕРЁД 5. Разг. Прежде, раньше, сперва. В. подумай, потом говори. Я в. загляну, дома ли он. Плата - в. (=авансом).

Comment: @М_Г А какие _альтернативные_ варианты платы на постоянной основе можно предположить? Мне понятен только вариант повторяемости: следующий трёхмесячный  платёж должен поступить до окончания уже оплаченного срока, тогда договор продлевается арендодателем.

Comment: @Alex_ander, Ваш вариант наибилее логичен, но ввиду нечеткости определения "на постоянной основе" можно предположить, что кому-то придет в голову другая, даже невероятная трактовка. (В юридических документах нужно и это предусматривать) Например, договор заключается на год с правом его продления еще на год в конце каждого года аренды. Каждый раз при продлении договора (раз в год) вносится арендная плата за три месяца вперед (вот Вам и постоянная основа), а затем помесячно.